# How to arrange multi partitions in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, hadoop-partitioning

say i have a order table, which contains multi time column(spend_time,expire_time,withdraw_time),
usually,i will query the table with the above column independently,so how do i create the partitions?

```
order_no | spend_time   | expire_time   | withdraw_time | spend_amount  
A001     | 2017/5/1     | 2017/6/1      | 2017/6/2      | 100   
A002     | 2017/4/1     | 2017/4/19     | 2017/4/25     | 500   
A003     | 2017/3/1     | 2017/3/19     | 2017/3/25     | 1000
```

Usually the business  situation is to calculate total spend_amount between certain spend_time or expire_time or withdraw_time, or the combination of the 3.

But with 3 time dimensions cross combination(each has about 1000 partitions) can be a lot of partitions(1000*1000*1000),is that ok and efficient?

my solution is that i create 3 tables with 3 different columns.Is this a efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the basic knowledge regarding partitions in Hive?

Comment: yes,but not much,the partitions are stored as file folders,if i create 3 partitions(A,B,C), then the table is stored like tablename/A-partition/B-partition/C-partition/file-block.
My questions is that, if i only query where filter C or even deeper inside partitions ,will the query be efficient?(of course it's not as efficient as A due to the partition order)
Is there a balance between partition numbers and performance?

Comment: O.K. Please show a data sample and example of the partitions values you want to use

Comment: (1) Please delete the comment and add the additional information to your post (2) Give a data sample with multiple rows. (3) Is that your actual date format?(!)

Comment: Sorry about the format,i have add a picture about the data. 

It's a table with 3 time dimensions: spend_time,expire_time,withdraw_time.
Sometimes i need to query with only one dimension,sometimes might be two, how do i arrange the partitions?
Just by the frequency of the dimensions i used? 
But with 3 time dimensions cross combination(each has about 1000 partitions) can be a lot of partitions(1000*1000*1000),is that ok and efficient?

Comment: i have re-format the question,please check it again,thanks!

Comment: (1) How many records do you have in your table? (2) Is that the real date format you are using? (3) You can't partition an existing table. You'll have to create a new table. (4) One of the options is to partition by months (YYYY-MM).

Comment: About 30million, not very big,but used very frequent, partition by months might be a good choice.